# Update FreeBSD ports to specific version/time

Tags: freebsd

I know that i can use the command `Portsnap fetch update`
in order to update the ports tree.

My issue rises because i have 2 servers, one running php 5.2 (server a) and the other running 5.3 (server b)

I want to update the ports tree in server a to match the ports tree in server b exactly.

If i will run the command above it will update the ports tree to the latest version, causing the php port to update to versikn 5.4.13, which is not what i want.

How can i match the ports trees version?

Comment: Instead of syncing the ports tree you could build binary packages from ports on server b and install them on server a.

Comment: How do i do that? Right now i run `make install clean` on server b

Comment: Check the [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html) and [ports man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ports&amp;sektion=7) for details. `make package` will create a package in /usr/ports/packages you can use the pkg_add to install the binary package.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as a duplicate of the question about managing ports in a large environment (since that's really the crux of your problem) -- if that & the pointers about using SVN below don't work for you let me know and I'll reopen this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Craig pointed out](https://serverfault.com/questions/513252/update-freebsd-ports-to-specific-version-time#comment580804_513252) the officially-blessed way to deal with this is to use one machine to build "official" packages that you distribute to other hosts in your environment.
[This was discussed in another question/answer on Server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/364556/how-do-you-manage-and-deploy-freebsds-ports-in-a-large-environment), with a few options on how to go about implementing it in your environment.

---

If you still ***NEED*** to get the ports tree as it was on a specific date you can do so using `svn` (see [The Subversion Method](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html) for fetching ports, and read the subversion documentation or [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204243/update-svn-checkout-to-specific-date-including-externals)for more details on how to set your tree to a specific date/revision).